# RStudio : what is the code behind the export>save as image button?

Tags: r, graphics, png, rstudio, plotly

I try to find a way to save a plotly graph as png without installing orca (I'm not allowed to).
It appears that if I plot my graphics, lets say :

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano) %>% add_surface()
p
```

and then clic on export>save as image>Save as png, the resulting static plot is available on my computer

[image: 1]]

But If I try to use classical `png()` like this :

```
png("myvolcano.png")
plot_ly(z = ~volcano) %>% add_surface()
dev.off()
```

I get a blank png...
(while it's working for a classical `plot(1)` )

How to reproduce by code what I get from the menu bar ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is more a comment than an answer but my reputation does not allow me to comment.

You can use 2 strategies to export plotly graphs:

- use orca() function in the plotly pkg (if you ?orca will find all the explanations)
- use htmlwidgets::saveWidget(p, file = "myvolcano.html") which downloads in html format

In the past there was a function export() but it is deprecated now.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. I can't use orca, because it needs a previous installation to make the package work (either through conda or npm). You're right on htmlwidgets : I initially tried it as a workaround, unfortunately it's very slow to open and if I want to get the png out of it, I have to use package like webshot, which also need an external installation (phantomjs).